# Database Partitioning- partition columns

Tags: database, oracle, database-partitioning

I was reading about database partitioning from oracle documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm)(sales table). I got the concept that in range partitioning, you specify a column(or multiple columns) and give the corresponding range of values so that when you insert a value in table, it will go in related partitions making search efficient.

In the beginning of Range Partitioning section, it talks about the partitioning columns(sales_year, sales_month and sales_day) but those columns do not show in the create table statement. **What exactly is partitioning columns?** **Are partitioning columns different from table columns?**

Comment: The strings "sales_year", "sales_month", and "sales_day" don't appear in the link you provided so it's hard to guess what you're reading that might be causing confusion.  You partition on columns in the table, you can't partition on columns that don't exist in the table.

Comment: @Justin Sorry for the confusion.After you open the link, scroll down a little bit and there's a topic "Creating a Range-Partitioned Table". The first line contains about the partition column sale_year, sale_month and sale_day. Hope it help.s

Answer (score 1):

No, partitioning columns are not different than table columns. I guess you are talking about the sale_year, sale_month, and sale_day columns in the documentation link.

I think that the example given in the link is incorrect. The partition is based on time_id and there are no sale_year, sale_month, and sale_day columns in the table. I think this piece of documentation is copy paste of older Oracle versions and not been updated appropriately in this case.

You can search for sale_year in the below links and find the correct example.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67772/partiti.htm

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=z7UYI2-329MC&pg=PA462&lpg=PA462&dq=sale_year,+sale_month,+and+sale_day&source=bl&ots=j6_Pn7saNp&sig=YLwus8UqXzyhkG5_XxcY2wyV7kU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqPT3193MAhWBMI8KHUDPCCYQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=sale_year%2C%20sale_month%2C%20and%20sale_day&f=false